# lua nested for loop and table.insert creating multiple entries

Tags: for-loop, lua, nested, duplicates

Still learning here, so most likely there's a less complicated way to achieve my goals. This is a snippet I pulled from my code that 90% works as intended, but I'm failing on my last step.

```
    inv = {}
    
    for i = 23,mq.TLO.Me.NumBagSlots()+22 do
        inv[i] = {}
        for j = 1,mq.TLO.Me.Inventory(i).Container() do
            inv[i][j]={Item=mq.TLO.Me.Inventory(i).Item(j),bag=i,slot=j}
        end
    end
    
    local sortthatsucker={}
    for _,bags in pairs(inv) do
        for _,invcontainer in pairs(bags) do
            for _,_ in pairs(invcontainer) do
                local compactstring = tostring(invcontainer.Item).."-"..tostring(invcontainer.bag).."_"..tostring(invcontainer.slot)
                if tostring(invcontainer.Item) ~= "NULL" then
                    table.insert(sortthatsucker,compactstring)
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    table.sort(sortthatsucker)
    for k,v in pairs(sortthatsucker) do
        print(k,"-",v)
    end
```

Will currently extract, filter, and sort all items as I want, creating a compound string showing the item name and current "coords" if you will for simplified k,v table that's sortable by name, but due to I believe the 3 nested for loops to pull the data out, the table.insert will create three identical entries in the final table, albeit with unique key values for each entry.

ie:

```
163-shovel-23_10
164-shovel-23_10
165-shovel-23_10
166-tonsils-18_5
167-tonsils-18_5
168-tonsils-18_5
169-withers-6_12
170-withers-6_12
171-withers-6_12
```

etc...

My goal is to have this table with a single entry for each item found, and do a set of new nested for loops to pull the x and y values out of that string to interact with that item at that give coordinate and move it to a new x and y. If there was a way to create the initial table and interact with that, rather make it as a nested table to achieve the same result, that would also be beneficial, as I have not been able to figure that out after two weeks of trying and searching.

Comment: it looks like `for _,_ in pairs(invcontainer) do` loop is completely unneed, your arent using the variable from it what purpose does it serve? it probably loops 3 times but pulls the same data each time, and the 3 loops are because it has the keys slot, item and bag

Comment: that one is necessary because the loop above will only return a table string, inside this for loop returns the actual item, bag, slot info *shrug* I put it at the level where the output gave me the actual table values I needed?

Comment: the code in that loop could be moved into the loop above it and it would be the exact same thing, just fewer times.

Comment: You are correct. in prior attempts I must have done something differently that led me to believe I needed a new subset. I tried again, removing the third iteration of the for loop, and changed my pairs reference to the "bags" reference on the loop prior and it worked correctly this time. thank you for pointing that out.